# Make secondary navigation stay in place when primary category is hovered using only CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a navigation panel where you hover over the category you want and the list of pages for that category appears underneath, horizontally. I have the main bulk of it down but I don't know how to make the list of pages (secondary navigation part) stay in place after a category has been hovered over without using Javascript.

I'm developing using an old version of Firefox (10.0.1) due to work limitations.

Here is what I have:

```
<style>
body,a,ul,li{margin:0;padding:0;text-decoration: none}
*{font-family: verdana;font-size: 12px;color:#333;}
#nav{
    margin-left: 20px;
    width: 400px;
    height: 50px;
}
#nav:after{
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    width: 400px;
    height: 30px;
    background: #888;
    z-index: 0;
}
    #nav > ul{
        position: relative;
    }
    #nav > ul:before{
        content: "";
        display: table-cell;
        width: 100%;
    }
        #nav > ul > li{
            background: #ccc;
            height: 50px;
            display: table-cell;
            white-space: nowrap;
            vertical-align: middle;
            padding: 0 15px 0 15px;
        }
            #nav > ul > li > ul{
                background: #bbb;
                position: absolute;
                left: 0;
                display: table-cell;
                height: 30px;
                bottom: -30px;
                z-index: 1;
            }
                #nav > ul > li > ul > li{
                    background: #aaa;
                    display: none;
                    height: 30px;
                    padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
                    vertical-align: middle;
                }
                #nav > ul > li:hover > ul > li{
                    display: table-cell;
                }
</style>
<div id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Cat 1</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Cat 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Cat 3</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

[JsFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/BfBMU/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution:

```
#nav > ul > li:hover > ul:after{
    display: table-cell;
    content: "";
    width: 1000px;
}
```

This fills up the remaining whitespace in the second ul which makes it stay active when the cursor is over it.